# integrate Nutch 1.6 with Solr 4.3 IOException when running <nutch crawl urls -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/> Job Failed. Any ideas?

Tags: solr, indexing, nutch

I am trying to integrate Nutch 1.6 with Solr 4.3 (I copied the /apache-nutch-1.6/conf/schema-solr4.xml into collection1/conf/ and rename the file to schema.xml). I also tried Nutch1.5.1 to integrate with solr 4.3. In both situations I am getting IOException when running:

```
bash$ nutch crawl urls -solr http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/
```

Job Failed. Any ideas?

I figuered that one out myself, had to look at solr.log and add these fields below to schema.xml under collection1/conf

`<field name="host" type="string" stored="false" indexed="true"/>`
`<field name="segment" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>`
`<field name="digest" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>`
`<field name="boost" type="float" stored="true" indexed="false"/>`
`<field name="tstamp" type="date" stored="true" indexed="false"/>`
and it worked.

Comment: you should add logs at the your question. "Job failed" is insufficient  information for the problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes can you please put additional details from log. The possible cause may be you need to define the uniquekey in schema.xml file. like this

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>.
```

Answer (score 0):

vera,
i just use nutch 1.7 and solr 4.4.0.
i had problem in schema.xml file. i figure out to few change in schema file that change are below

copy ur usr/nutch 1.7/conf/ schema.xml to paste /usr/local/solr-4.4.0/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema and overridded after u change the field type="text" not a text_field.
change  to

content= text class 
change that
englishPorterFilterFactory to SnowballPorterFilterFactory

after add

field name="*version*" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"

field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"

its working fine for me vera..

Comment: Arul, am try to get nutch 1.7 and solr 4.4.0 working but getting the error Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed! when i do "bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8080/solr/#/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*". I have copied the schema file but not sure which field you are asking to change.